# Java Return BigInteger from String

Tags: java, java-calendar

I am generating number from date, I am using Integer.parseInt(myDateNumberString).

My problem is if the number is too large it will give me an error.

```
public Integer currentDate(){
        String current_date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        //int _current_date = Integer.parseInt(current_date); // Error, too big number
        int _current_date = new BigInteger(current_date).intValue();
        return _current_date; // Error, output: -51212897
    }
```

I want to get value like `201812250203`
If my date format without `mm` it is ok, but I need to declare it.

Comment: Use a different data type than int. Right now you are creating a `BigInteger` object and then immediately convert it to an int, which is a lot of fireworks to just parse `current_date` to an int

Comment: Can you use a long?

Comment: @KevinO same result with Long

Comment: `getTime` returns a `long`.  I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `intValue`, but the result of `getTime` is almost certainly what you want, if you want a numeric representation of a date.

Comment: Why not use an actual object meant for storing a date instead of just a numeric value?

Comment: Why not just simply do `public long currentDate() { return Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(); }` Also, why are you even converting that format to an int? Why not just keep it as a String?

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us the *actual* problem you're trying to solve, rather than your unsuccessful attempt at solving it.  The fact that a date won't fit into an int is *not* the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @All, I need Integer type of value to integrate my data.

Comment: That's not enough information about your problem.  Can you show us some more code?

Comment: @AjieKurniyawan, but _why_ do you need an Integer to store a formatted timestamp? Can you modify the function you are trying to pass this Integer value into?

Comment: why you don't cut to multi part after convert part by part

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: 201812250203 cannot fit into an `Integer`, so you are asking the impossible. That said I agree with others that you should use a proper date-time object rather than `Integer`, for example `LocalDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime` or `Instant`. I too recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## tl;dr

Use ISO 8601 strings to exchange date-time values, not a number faking as a date-time. Generally best to exchange moments in UTC rather than your own time zone.

```
Instant
.now()
.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MINUTES)
.toString()
```

> 2018-12-24T19:32:00Z

To minimize the use of delimiters, use the “basic” variation of ISO 8601 formats. We retain the `T` separating the year-month-day portion from the hour-minute portion. Dropping the `Z` indicating UTC is ill-advised, but if you insist.

```
OffsetDateTime
.now( ZoneOffset.UTC )
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMdd'T'HHmm" ) 
)
```

> 20181224T1936

Using an integer to represent a date-time string is ill-advised, but if you insist.

```
new BigInteger( 
    OffsetDateTime
    .now( ZoneOffset.UTC )
    .format(
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmm" ) 
    )
)
.toString()
```

> 201812241939

A 32-bit integer (`int`, `Integer`) is limited to 2,147,483,647. Your fake-datetime number of 2,018,123,581,939 is too large for that. You could use a 64-bit integer (`long`, `Long`). But, again, I must say this is a poor way to represent date-time values.

```
new BigInteger( 
    OffsetDateTime
    .now( ZoneOffset.UTC )
    .format(
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmm" ) 
    )
)
.longValue()
```

> 201812241939

Or, skip `BigInteger` and use `Long`.

```
Long
.parseLong(
    OffsetDateTime
    .now( ZoneOffset.UTC )
    .format(
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmm" ) 
    )
)
```

> 201812241939

## java.time

You are using terrible old date-time classes (`SimpleDateFormat`, `Calendar`) that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310.

### `ZonedDateTime`

To get the current date and time as seen through the wall-clock time used the people of a particular region, specify a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

### `DateTimeFormatter`

To generate a string in the format of YYYYMMDDHHMM, use `DateTimeFormatter` class.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHss" ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

### Use appropriate data types

I strongly discourage you from trying to represent this value as a number. For date-time values, use date-time objects (*java.time* objects). For exchanging date-time values as text, generate strings in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. The `ZonedDateTime::toString` method wisely extends the standard by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.

```
String output = zdt.toString() ;  // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format wisely extended to append the name of the time zone in square brackets.
```

But if you insist on doing the number thing, here goes.

```
BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger( zdt.format( f ) ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Your codes require API 26, I need to make old device works using my apps. I 
 am targetting minSdkVersion 16

Comment: @AjieKurniyawan Reread my Answer, looking for mention of “earlier Android”.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BigInteger number = new BigInteger(string);`, which parses the given string as a BigInteger.

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(java.lang.String)) say:

> Constructs a new BigInteger by parsing value. The string
>   representation consists of an optional plus or minus sign followed by
>   a non-empty sequence of decimal digits. Digits are interpreted as if
>   by Character.digit(char,10).

Comment: `BigInteger` is a red herring here.

Comment: Based on the comments that assume OP's approach is wrong, yes. However, OP specifically asked how to parse a String to a BigInteger and this answer provides that information. If OP had asked "what's a better way to handle timestamps" this answer wouldn't be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Change the return type of the method to long and the returning variable as well:

EDIT: Get rid of the .intValue() method and change the return type of the method to the BigInteger and the variable too.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(currentDate());
}

public static BigInteger currentDate() {
    String current_date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    // int _current_date = Integer.parseInt(current_date);
    BigInteger _current_date = new BigInteger(current_date);
    return _current_date;
}
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).